# reduce image size inside a modal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using a popup component from react-popup. I add an image into it but the image stretches to the full width and length. How can I reduce it's size?

```
export default () => (
  <Popup
    trigger={<Button className="button" variant="contained" color="primary" > Click me! </Button>}
    modal
    nested
  >
    {(close: any) => (
      <div className="modal">
        <button className="close" onClick={close}>
          &times;
        </button>
        <div className="header"> Heading</div>
        <div className="content">
          {' '}
          <div className="car">
          <img src={car} alt="car" />
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
       Text
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  </Popup>
);
```

Style:

```
  .car {
    width: 10;
  }
```

I tried creating a sandbox but it gives a material UI error:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hooks-yhik1?file=/src/Popup.tsx

The modal opens when you click on the button

Comment: Why are you using `reactjs-popup` instead of MUI's [`Dialog`](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the img tag in the css and put a valid unit like px or %

Component

```
<div className="modal">
    <button className="close" onClick={close}>
      &times;
    </button>
    <div className="header"> Guide </div>
    <div className="content">
      {" "}
      <img src={car} alt="charts" className="charts" />
      <br />
      This example demonstrates the
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.charts {
  width: 20%;
}
```